# Child of window.open doesn't call function in parent window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

### parent.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openWin()
            {
                myWindow=window.open('child.html','','width=200,height=100');
            }
            function callback(){
                alert("test");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Open 'myWindow'" onclick="openWin()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

### child.html

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          window.opener.callback();
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the problem is that the child page calls parent's page callback function in FF, IE but not in Chrome.

Any idea ?

Comment: Works for me. Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Did you try on child page put: <body onload="javascript:window.opener.callback();" ???

Comment: @Vismari Don't put `javascript:` scheme in event attributes. Just put your code. The `javascript:` fragment is interpreted as a label, it is unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem happens because of Chrome security error. Domains, protocols and ports must match. But it also happens when page is open from local files system.

Open your page from server, it should be without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the way how chrome run javascript. Chrome sometimes run the js so fast and early and even the DOM is not ready for manipulation. Try this in your child.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){window.opener.callback();}, 100);
</script>
```

I am not sure if this is the exact problem for you, I encountered this problem with jQuery.ready() on chrome.

Comment: ...mmm I think that the DOM of the opener is surely already loaded.